# how to add a row of data to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner trying to append rows of data via a for loop to a dataframe but keep getting

`TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"`

Here is the relevant code:

```
myCols = ['Ticker', 'Name', 'Age', 'Height']  
finalData = pd.DataFrame(columns=myCols)
```

> ```
>  listOfPerson=[{Name: 'John', Age: '27', Height '115'},{Name: 'Jill', Age: '25', Height '110'}]
>  for person in listOfPerson:
>     finalData.append(pd.Series([
>         person.name,
>         person.age,
>         person.height,
>         'N/A'
>     ], index=myCols
>     ), ignore_index = True, axis=1)
> ```

Any tips are appreciated and let me know if any further info is needed.

I have tried reading up on other forum posts and have tried .concat() but it also tells me it does not exist. I cannot seem to figure it out. Perhaps it is a datatype error and the documentation online is just confusing.

Comment: Getting this error, you might be using an old version of pandas. What version are you running?

Comment: Aslo, welcome to SO! Please have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: `append` is no longer available in the Pandas v2. But `concat` can be used. Please provide a reproducible code and data example demonstrating your problem with concat.

Comment: Don't grow a DataFrame in a loop, the behavior is quadratic. Just use the DataFrame constructor directly: `df = pd.DataFrame(listOfPerson)`. Much easier, much more efficient...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **AttributeError** you're encountering (`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'`) is due to how the `append()` method works in Pandas. It doesn't modify the DataFrame in place; instead, it returns a new DataFrame with the appended data. Here's how you can modify your code to fix this issue:

```py
import pandas as pd

myCols = ['Ticker', 'Price', 'One-Yr Price Return', 'Number of Shares to purchase']
finalData = pd.DataFrame(columns=myCols)

for symbol in symbolStrings[0].split(','):
    new_row = pd.Series([
        symbol,
        latestData[symbol].vwap,
        'na',
        'na'
    ], index=myCols)
    finalData = finalData.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

print(finalData)
```

In this corrected version, we're creating a new row using a `pd.Series` object and then using the `append()` method to add the new row to the `finalData` DataFrame. It's important to assign the result of `append()` back to the `finalData` variable to update the DataFrame.

Additionally, please keep in mind that having spaces in column names (e.g., `Number of Shares to purchase`) can sometimes lead to confusion. It's generally a good practice to avoid spaces in column names. You might consider using underscores or camel case instead.

Remember to adjust `symbolStrings` and `latestData` according to your actual data sources.

---

Hopefully, this solution helps you resolve the issue. If you have any further questions or need additional assistance, feel free to ask!

Comment: Great explanation thank you! I edited my code as someone said I should create a reproducable example so if you want to edit your solution so that it makes more sense to other people who see this feel free to.

Comment: This is not a good pandas approach. Never grow a DataFrame in a loop. Also, now `append` was removed from the API. The correct way is to use the DataFrame constructor directly: `df = pd.DataFrame(listOfPerson)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Answer (score 0):

The other answer already shows how to fix your code.

Generally append would be slow, because on each append, it needs to make a complete copy of the dataframe.
For performance I recommend first creating the list (listOfPerson) in memory and then constructing the dataframe all at once, like this:

```py
myCols = ['Ticker', 'Name', 'Age', 'Height']
finalData = pd.DataFrame(columns=myCols)
listOfPerson = [{'Name': 'John', 'Age': '27', 'Height': '115'}, {'Name': 'Jill', 'Age': '25', 'Height': '110'}]

finalData = pd.DataFrame(listOfPerson, columns=myCols)
print(f"{finalData=}")
```